# How to get return value of function of angular2 in html or markup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Is there anyway to put the return value of a function in the markup for example:

```
  <p> Days diff {{compareDays(task.dueDate)}}</p>
```

this is my function:

```
public compareDays(date: Date): string {
    let oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
    let diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((date.getTime() - this.today.getTime()) / (oneDay)));

    return diffDays.toString();
}
```

Comment: That should work.  What is your issue?  Is `task` defined on your component?

Comment: Even if this is possible I would create a property that would encapsulate that logic, and use that in the view.

Comment: The method will be called every time change detection is run (that is usually quite often) therefor @AdrianFaciu's suggestion is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Sorry the method was alright it was a bug in other side that didn´t let the method work.